# Enable or disable lines in xml file based on Macro

Tags: xml

I want to enable or disable lines in xml file based on a macro.I use a xml file to input all the paths for my project, is it possible to enable few paths based on a macro used in the project.for example,

```
    **<>/path1/<>
    if (MACRO>1)
    <>/path2/<>
    <>/path3/<>
    endif
   <>/path4/<>**
```

Comment: please neglect the **

Comment: There's nothing in XML itself that will do this, but there are plenty of templating languages that allow you to generate XML conditionally: XSLT, Freemarker, etc etc.